# Programa Java não encontra o caminho do relatorio jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, relatório, ireport, jasper

Fiz um pequeno programa em java para gerar relatorios de orçamento, usei para tanto o jasper Ireport, fiz, testei, gerou os orçamentos tudo funcionando no meu computador. 
Quando instalei no computador de um amigo funcionou tudo certo exceto os relatórios, nem chega a aparecer em branco, fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No código, o caminho da imagem, ao que parece, está posto de forma correta.

```
public void imprimeRelatorio() {

        ConexaoMySql co = new ConexaoMySql();
        co.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poc");
        co.setUsuario("root");
        co.setSenha("");

         String src = "C:\\orcamento.jasper";


        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parametros.put("id",(Integer.parseInt(inpId.getText())));
          System.out.println("parametros="+parametros);


      JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
        try {
            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(src, parametros, co.getConnection());
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TelaControle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        view.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("view" +view);

    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Executei pelo cmd para ver a saída e realmente o caminho da imagem parece estar correto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mais estranho é que no meu computador funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dois eram os erros: 
como o windows daquela máquina está configurado para não mostrar a extensão dos arquivos, o nome do arquivo estava divergente, sendo assim eu renomeei do arquivo para apenas `orcamento`.

O segundo erro estava no próprio arquivo do relatório pois continha um logotipo que estava com o caminho das pastas do outro computador. Quando eu corrigi isso, resolveu o problema e gerou os relatórios normalmente. Obrigado.